# How can I aggregate Google Analytics events by event name?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics-events

How can I aggregate events by name?

We're running focus groups on our new eCommerce site and I'm collecting events which appear in GA as:

When user clicks a product:

```
Event Category:   Event Action:
Clicked Product   clicked product: productX - Group a - Round 1
```

When user carts this product:

```
Event Category:   Event Action:
Carted Product    added product to cart: productX (x1) - Group a - Round 1
```

**Question**: So I want to be able to see how many times this specific event string, `clicked product: productX - Group a - Round 1`, was emitted.

---

For carting, the event is produced by:

```
gtag('event', `added product to cart: ${$scope.product.name} - ${$scope.product.volume} (x${$scope.productQuantity}) - Group ${localStorage.getItem(`focus_group`)} - Round ${localStorage.getItem(`focus_round`)}`, {
    'event_category': `Carted Product`,
    'event_label': 'Product'
});
```

But I'm only able to see these events under `REAL TIME --> EVENTS`. They aren't aggregated, and disappear shortly after.

[image]

If I go to `BEHAVIOR --> EVENTS --> OVERVIEW`, there's no events or aggregation by event name:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How long have you given the data to show up in the Behavior > Events > Overview report? It will take a day to appear there (theoretically it could be two days, but that is unlikely for Events). Since you are seeing your events in the Real-Time report, there should not be a problem with them appearing in the Events reports after the delay.

At that point I think you will want the report Behavior > Events > Top Events, instead of the Overview report. That report will open with Event Categories showing, and you can click into `Clicked Product` to see the Event Actions you are interested in.

It is also possible to show Event Actions without clicking into a specific category, by changing the Primary Dimension to Event Action (alternate Primary Dimensions are available as links just above the report table). That would allow you to see both click and add-to-cart activity together.

A little side note: If you haven't set up [Enhanced Ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/enhanced-ecommerce) tracking, I would recommend it as a very useful tool for any ecommerce site. However, for the situation you describe, I think I would want events like the ones you have set up even if I also had Enhanced Ecommerce.